# Importing large number of records with Angular and laravel stops

Tags: php, angular, laravel, nginx

I am developing a service with angular that sends an array with lots of objects to a server with laravel to be inserted or updated. When I send 3000 or 5000 records, the service works normally, but when the records are more than 5000, something strange happens.

I have a websocket running with redis on the server to give functionality to a progress bar that indicates the progress of importing the records.
When there are many records, the procedures on the server are re-executed. Records that have already been inserted or updated do the same procedure again. This I know because in the database I see the auto incremental id, the time and date of insertion or update of the registry.

My first indication that the process was repeating though was that the progress bar was restarting.
As if this were no longer problematic, in the second unexpected execution of the process, the http request ends and returns ERR_empty_response.

Before starting the insert or update process, I open a transaction and only execute a commit if the process runs successfully. Obviously if it doesn't run a rollback

Do you have any idea what it could be?

My server's runtime environment is nginx, Laravel 5.8 (php).
The app that consumes the service is developed with Angular 9

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what is happening is that your job is timing out and is restarted automatically because Laravel "thinks" it failed, since it is not returning a successful response.

I would suggest you split your big job into smaller jobs. Meaning your "big" job receives all these requests, but the job itself creates 5000 small jobs that process each one individually.  So the big job will return a successful response immediately and Redis will process each small job whenever possible.

Comment: I thought about easing server work by easing the load, but I can't think of an efficient way to commit to BD as soon as the job is done.

How could I send "threads" of records while the request is still active?

Comment: You can't with this method.  In this method, every little Job is a "session" by itself